# THREE.js use background material

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, webgl

My goal is to composite 3D objects onto a panorama. I have got the objects in and have lined them up fine with the correct perspective. What i need is a way to implement a useBackground shader you see in softwares like Maya and Max into three.js.

To be more clear, I want to get the shadow cast onto a proxy ground I have created. The ground **should not** be visible but the shadow cast on it **should** be visible. If you can help me or guide me to the right direction. Do I need to create a custom shader or is there a way already to render only the shadow cast on the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution from the Internet :P. 
I had to create a shader where I the shadowColor is subtracted from the alpha of the GL_FragColor

here is the code for the fragment shader . You can use the vertex shader from the BasicMaterial.

```
planeFragmentShader = [

            "uniform vec3 diffuse;",
            "uniform float opacity;",

            THREE.ShaderChunk["color_pars_fragment"],
            THREE.ShaderChunk["map_pars_fragment"],
            THREE.ShaderChunk["lightmap_pars_fragment"],
            THREE.ShaderChunk["envmap_pars_fragment"],
            THREE.ShaderChunk["fog_pars_fragment"],
            THREE.ShaderChunk["shadowmap_pars_fragment"],
            THREE.ShaderChunk["specularmap_pars_fragment"],

            "void main() {",

            "gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );",

            THREE.ShaderChunk["map_fragment"],
            THREE.ShaderChunk["alphatest_fragment"],
            THREE.ShaderChunk["specularmap_fragment"],
            THREE.ShaderChunk["lightmap_fragment"],
            THREE.ShaderChunk["color_fragment"],
            THREE.ShaderChunk["envmap_fragment"],
            THREE.ShaderChunk["shadowmap_fragment"],
            THREE.ShaderChunk["linear_to_gamma_fragment"],
            THREE.ShaderChunk["fog_fragment"],

            "gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 - shadowColor.x );",

            "}"
        ].join("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

The three.js skinning example uses a shadow like that. Make sure that the objects have their castShadow properties set to true and that the lights are in the right place. http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_skinning_morph.html

```
// GROUND

var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { emissive: 0xbbbbbb } );
var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 16000, 16000 );

var ground = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, groundMaterial );
ground.position.set( 0, FLOOR, 0 );
ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
scene.add( ground );

ground.receiveShadow = true;
```

Comment: The groundMaterial here has a color of OxFFFFFF by default which matches the background color making it blend with the background . I have a photograph in the background, hence a single color wont work. I just want the object to have the background projected onto it so that it doesn't show up in the render but just the shadow cast on it shows up. Or, if the objects color can be multiplied over the background color like a photoshop filter. If there is a way to do that, it could solve the problem as well. Any direction would help.